# Woocommerce Theme Reviews / Comments

Tags: theme-development, comments, woocommerce-offtopic

Ok so i'm creating a Wordpress theme and i'm at the point where i'm trying to get a list of the reviews but the default `comments_template()` HTML isn't how I need it.

I don't have a `/comments.php` file in my theme root but i'm trying to use this:

```
comments_template( 'single-product/reviews.php' );
```

I don't know why but it's showing the default code with the avatar images and that. I don't need this. Basically I just need their name and 5 stars (using font-awesome). I know I don't have much code to show as i'm getting stuck at the comments template. Even if I try `comments_template( '' );` it displays the default wp template.

This comments function is is called from `content-single-product.php` if that is anything. It might be important to note i'm building this ontop of underscores, that might.

Would it be worth just coding the review section manually? I'm only listing the reviews and outputting the form right?

Answer (score 0):

`content-single-product.php` sounds like a woocommerce template, which is located here `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates`. You can override this template in your theme or child them by creating a file `wp-content/themes/your-theme/woocommerce/content-single-product.php`.

Comment: Yea it works fine but my problem is with displaying the comments/reviews. The default woocommerce themes have the comments system rooted in some tab system so it's difficult to look at other themes and see where i'm going wrong

Comment: Mind I ask, what theme you are using? Also, just to make sure comments are enabled ( Navigate to settings -> Discussion, check "Allow people to post comments on new articles" ). You can also check on the edit product page (Product Data -> Advanced check "Enable reviews")

Comment: Yea comments and all that are enabled and it's my own theme i'm writing. I just can't use the comments_templage correctly. All i want to do is list the rating and name but not with the default wordpress list.